# Outside of AppDelegate, how do I contain a UIViewController in UINavigationController before I basically `performSegueWIthIdentifier` to it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I understand the concept in AppDelegate.

The basics go like this:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: “Main”, bundle: nil)

var mainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(
“MainViewController”) as! UIViewController

var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

self.window?.rootViewController = navController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This will successfully make your mainViewController a NavigationController and function like so.

I don't want to do this in AppDelegate.

I have a UIViewController called A that **is not** contained in a UINavigationController. From A, what I do now is I `performSegueWithIdentifier` to another UIViewController called B. I want to **programmatically** make B contained in a UINavigationController. I don't want to achieve this in the Storyboard. This has to be done programmatically.

I guess I would have to use the `mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(...)` to instantiate B and then wrap it in a UINavigationController somewhere in A (preferably where I plan to segue to B). Then, I get to B someway other than `performSegueWithIdentifier`? Because if I perform the segue, then it won't go to the B I wrapped in a UINavigationController.

I hope that wasn't too complicated, but I can offer details if anything doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this would be similar to what you have in your code sample except for actually displaying the new view controller. Let's say you have a method in view controller A that is supposed to show view controller B, you might do something like this:

```
func showViewControllerB() {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewControllerB = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerB)
    presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is definitely it. I had a good feeling this was it, but... was on the road so I couldn't confirm :P. Thanks!